# How do I solve this trigonometric system.

Tags: trigonometry

I'm working in a problem where you have to find the local extrema of a given $f(x,y)$. I'm stuck with this system and I don't know how to tuckle it down. $x$ and $y$ go from $0$ to $2\pi$.

$$\cos(x) - \sin(x+y) = 0$$

$$\cos(y) - \sin(x+y) = 0$$

Comment: Hint: The two equations imply $\cos(x)=\cos(y)$. What does that tell us about $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Well firstly you know that $\cos(x) = \cos(y)$ so $x = y$ or $x = 2\pi - y$.